# Azure Backup Server on Azure VM to Protect on-premises workloads

Tags: backup, azure, vmware-server

I need to protect two VMware instances in a on-prem environment and want to achieve this by using Azure with Azure Backup and Azure Backup Server.

The following image shows a referencing architecture:

[image]

We really prefer to deploy the Azure Backup Server on a IaaS Azure VM, but there it comes my doubt: where the Azure Backup Server role can be distributed?

The official docs say that a on-prem server or a IaaS azure VM can be used both.
But later ...

> Azure Backup Server inherits much of the workload backup functionality from Data Protection Manager (DPM). This article links to DPM documentation to explain some of the shared functionality

(...)

> Protecting workloads with Azure Backup Server has many nuances. The article, Install DPM as an Azure virtual machine, helps explain these nuances. Before deploying the machine, read this article completely.

The linked article says:

> DPM running as an Azure virtual machine can’t protect on-premises data.

Now, it is clear that a azure distribution of DPM does not protect on-prem workloads. But is this true for Azure Backup Server?

Did someone had experiences with Azure Backup Server with a similar configuration?

Comment: So you're asking if your Azure VM running MABS can back up on premises data and workloads?

Comment: @joeqwerty Exactly.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative solution, you can configure a compact on-site backup repository powered by either Veeam + AWS VTL Gateway or Veeam + StarWind Cloud VTL and let VTL itself offload virtual tape images to AWS S3 or Glacier. AWS VTL Gateway is available for free, while StarWind VTL is a paid software with some extra features and additional support of Azure and Backblaze.

I have configured similar setups for our clients and it just works. CapEx is significant but you get more flexibility and decreased costs in a long run. Tapes are also must-have for companies who care about ransomware protection and this is the benefit I value personally.